# Open Page Only After Redirecting

Tags: php, html

My question is may be foolish. But I want to know, if there is any code that prevent the page opening if tried with link but opens only after . if it's link is from another page.

for example, if i have a form on page **contact.php** and user gets redirected to page **contact_success.php**.

Now I want, if anybody tried to open **contact_success.php** page directly from browser address bar, it should not be get opened. It should be get opened only after form submission from **contact.php** page..

Comment: `<?php if ($_POST['confirm'] != 'success') header("Location: contact.php"); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is just to use an `if` check on the `contact_success.php` page like

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST"){
    //display page
} else {
    echo 'You cannot view this page.';
    //add redirect, if you like
}
```

Comment: One could still use a curl or similar and access the page (only via POST)

Comment: @kingkero Good point. But the OP asked about accessing the page directly from the browser address bar.

Answer (score 1):

Set a session or a cookie for the user in the contact.php, and then in the contact_sucess.php you can check if it exists.

for exmaple:

contact.php:

```
<?php
$_SESSION['visited_login'] = 'yes';
?>
```

contact_sucess.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['visited_login']) && $_SESSION['visited_login']=="yes") {
    // output tanks
} else {
    echo "go away";
    die;
}
?>
```

Comment: I think one should avoid short open PHP tags, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

You can use session for that example:

let say when you submit the contact form there is a page where in you will process the user input and i will use(refer to the #1)

1. contact_process.php

   $_SESSION['success'] = 'success';

   ```
   (this code will create a session)
   ```

   then once success in processing the user input there is another page like(refer to # 2)
2. contact_success.php

   if(isset($_SESSION['success'])

   {

   ```
        //Output if it is success

   }
   ```

   else{

   header('location:contact.php');

   }

(this code will check if session is existing if yes the desired output will show and if not it should turn back to contact.php)

you can easily learn session here http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp